# Whenever ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, cron, whenever

In my schedule:

```
every 10.minutes do
  runner "Model.method"
end
```

Whenever created this in my crontabs

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/projects/Monitoring && script/rails runner -e development '\''Model.method'\'''
```

I tried to run the command in my console and it works. Why does it not work automaticly, i am going insane!

In my syslog

```
Mar 11 11:38:01 UbuntuRails CRON[20050]: (ruben) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/projects/Monitoring && script/rails runner -e development '\''Ping.check_pings'\''')
Mar 11 11:38:01 UbuntuRails CRON[20048]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Mar 11 11:38:01 UbuntuRails CRON[20047]: (CRON) error (grandchild #20050 failed with exit status 1)
Mar 11 11:38:01 UbuntuRails CRON[20047]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Comment: Do you have cron running locally?  You can also add `set :output, File.join(path, 'log', 'cron.log')` in your schedule.rb to log the output.

Answer (score 3):

I am on Ubuntu 10.10 and had the same problem.
Turns out the -l option does not load the environment as expected, but -i does. (see [this issue](https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/106))

As the issue thread states, the fix is to edit your schedule.rb and add:

```
set :job_template, "/bin/bash -i -c ':job'"
```

Cheers